# How to get the location of a certain element in all the given DataFrame (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I was struggling as I did not find where and how may I get the indices like row number and column number of my DataFrame. I then resolved this issue and had written a code which may do this job and thought about sharing it here as an answer to the question. Moreover, if there is an easier way one may add value as an answer.

Suppose you are given this dataframe and would like to locate where did 2 appear in that particular dataframe (df)

```
d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
   ....:      'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Is there a way to say that it is located in `df.ix[1,0]` and `df.ix[2,1]`

Comment: `list(df.stack()[df.stack() == 2].index)` with exact column and index values or use `np.column_stack(np.where(df == 2))` for positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the row, column pairs as tuples with respect to the `index` and `columns` object's values

```
s = df.eq(2).stack()
s[s].index.values

array([('b', 'one'), ('c', 'two')], dtype=object)
```

To get the positions, construct a new dataframe without the index or columns

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df.values).eq(2).stack()
s[s].index.values

array([(1, 0), (2, 1)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it I reach the following I wrote a function

```
def Get_indcies(df,b):
    t=np.where(df.values == b)
    return np.column_stack((t[0],t[1]))
```

In this case, the answer would be

```
t=Get_indcies(df,2)
```

will give you

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

hence the elements show exactly where they are located

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in range(0,df.shape[0]):

    s = df.eq(value-what you want to serch).stack()
    print(s[s].index.values)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.